# grep multiple words using results from previous grep

Tags: grep, pipe

I have a large set of files, which I want to search in.

I want to find all words - and only the words - that are surrounded by `X`. I do this with lookbehind and lookahead:

```
grep -rhoP "(?<=X)[a-zA-Z0-9_]*(?=X)" .
```

Now I want to know if there are words - with full context - from the previous result that are surrounded with `Y`. I can do that for one specific word `abc`

```
grep -rP "(?<=Y)abc(?=Y)" .
```

But how can I pipe the two commands together?

Update

I have a large set of C-files.
All our api functions are first declared in one of our many .h files, and used in one of our many .c files and inlined .h files.

Some functions may not be accessed directly, but through a function pointer, but that proves to be a great hindrance for development. For this purpose, we made some macro's (`FP` and `CALL`) to be able to easily turn on and off this requirement.

```
FP(DoThis)
void DoThis(void);
```

- With the requirement *ON*, `FP` defines a function pointer - in this case for `DoThis` - which can be used later on by using `CALL(DoThis)();`.
- With the requirement *OFF*, `FP` is expanded to nothing, and `CALL(DoThis)` is expanded to just `DoThis`.

A list of all functions for which a function pointer is created this way can be fetched by:

```
grep -rhoP "(?<=FP\()[a-zA-Z0-9_]*(?=\))" .
```

A list of all locations where the function pointer for function DoThis is used can be fetched by:

```
grep -rP "(?<=CALL\()DoThis(?=\))" .
```

Now I want to have a list of all locations where the function pointer for any function created using `FP` and `CALL` can be fetched.
So somehow, I want to chain the two greps together, so that each result from the first grep is fed to the second, and the final results are grouped together.

Comment: does `grep -rhoP "(?<=X)[a-zA-Z0-9_]*(?=X)" .|grep -P "(?<=Y).*(?=Y)"` work for you?

Comment: @Kent No. The results from the second grep will likely come from different files than the results from the first grep. The second grep really needs to search over all files again.

Comment: oh, I misunderstood you. so the two greps have nothing to do with each other, but you want get the result in one shot. then this? `grep -rhoP "(?<=X)[a-zA-Z0-9_]*(?=X)|(?<=Y)[a-zA-Z0-9_]*(?=Y)" .`

Comment: so it is a matter of using `grep -e something -e someotherthing`, right?

Comment: @kent I thanks for your ideas, but it seems I'm bad at asking the right question. I updated it, hoping it will be more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this good sir

```sh
grep -rho 'XY[a-zA-Z0-9_]*YX' . | sed 's/[XY]//g'
```